# Adding values that occur within same month: mysql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a table like this:

```
Date                     Name     Qty
2016-09-13 00:00:00      John     2
2016-09-15 00:00:00      Matt     3
2016-09-21 00:00:00      Rich     1
2016-09-23 00:00:00      Matt     1
2016-10-05 00:00:00      John     1
2016-10-07 00:00:00      Matt     3
2016-10-12 00:00:00      Rich     0
2016-10-23 00:00:00      Matt     2
```

How can I do, using MySQL, to retrieve the addition of all the Qty values that corresponds to the same month and place that info on a view?

Comment: So you wish to sum `Qty`, and group by the month name (and presumably year) of `Date`?

Comment: Use `group by month(your_date_column)`

Comment: @EatPeanutButter You need the year too.

Comment: There could be rows with dates from different years

Comment: The original has data with different years. I just tried to "simplify" my question

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga but You need sum of same month with same year or all years?

Comment: month with the same year

Comment: `GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)`

Comment: `select sum(Qty), month(your_date), year(your_date) from your_table group by year(your_date), month(your_date)`

Comment: Thanks guys. I used: SELECT month(Date), sum(Qty) FROM mytable
group by year(Date), month(Date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want could be one of the following queries:

```
SELECT YEAR(`Date`) AS yr, MONTH(`Date`) AS mnt, SUM(Qty) AS Qty
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`), MONTH(`Date`)
```

or

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `Date`) AS mnt, SUM(Qty) as Qty
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `Date`)
```

This query should produce something like this:

```
 mnt     | qty
---------+-----
 2016-09 | 7
 2016-10 | 6
```

The MySQL function [`EXTRACT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) is able to return only some [components of a date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(Qty) as sum, month(date) as month, year(date) as year FROM table_name GROUP BY month(date), year(date)
```

will return

```
 sum    month   year    
 4      12      2015
 10     12      2016
```

Comment: Grouping by year first and then by month sounds more appropriate if the resultset is used for display.